# Performance with reverse proxy with HTTP/2 and backend service HTTP/1.1

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, http2, nginx-reverse-proxy

My current setup is using NGINX (1.19) as a reverse proxy that handles TLS termination and supports HTTP/2. This server connects to a backend service in the internal network trough plain HTTP.

To connect to the upstream server, NGINX only uses HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 ([proxy_http_version](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version) directive) because HTTP/2 only works with secure connections.

I'm trying to understand if this setup will supose an increased overhead. As, if I undestand correctly, if the client connects to the proxy using a single TCP connection, and send requests trough N streams, the reverse proxy will have to stablish N new TCP connections to the upstream.

I've tried to run a few tests with this setup but have not found great differences.

Is it better to just enable HTTP/1.1 in the proxy instead of HTTP/2 if the backend service will just use HTTP/1.1?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That answer provides a lot of details that helped me clear this issue